# Ionic modal always open automatically

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a form placed in modal it supposed to open when user click on button but instead it opens automatically as soon as user loads the page.

## Issue

I have imported my modal into my page `module.ts` file and it makes modal open automatically. If I remove it form module page then I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for ContactSupplierPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for ContactSupplierPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

**So the problem now is:**

1. If i add my modal to module page it opens automatically
2. If I don't add it to module page it gets error and won't open.

## code

`list-detail.module.ts (suppose to have modal in it)`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ListDetailPage } from './list-detail.page';
import { ContactSupplierPageModule } from '../contact-supplier/contact-supplier.module'; //here

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ListDetailPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ContactSupplierPageModule, //here
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ListDetailPage]
})
export class ListDetailPageModule {}
```

`list-detail.page.ts`

```
async contactSupplier() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: ContactSupplierPage
    });
    return await modal.present();
}
```

`list-detail.html`

```
<ion-footer (click)="contactSupplier()">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Contact Supplier</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## SOLVED

I had to add my modal module in `app.module.ts` file instead of my page module file.

Now working just fine.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    ContactSupplierPageModule, // here
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Hope it help others.

Answer (score 1):

To me it was strange since that was happening because i had arrange the modal module to come before the page module.

```
 ModalPageModule,
 MyPageRoutingModule,

changed to 

  MyPageRoutingModule
  ModalPageModule,
```